# Custom Preference Including EditText

Tags: android, input, android-edittext, autosuggest

I am creating an custom preference which contains an `EditText`.

The problem is when user clicks the `EdiText` for input suggestion box opens up and `EditText` looses focus. When `EditText` is clicked again for input, no problem occurs until 'blank space' is entered, which results in suggestion box and hence loss of focus.

What I mean by suggestion box is the box which pops up when entering text in `EditText`

[image: Suggestion Box on EditText]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable Auto Suggestion by using `android:inputType="textFilter"` attribute in your XML file.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution that worked for me:
In AndroidMenifest.xml add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in the activity.

Found here:
http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg132688.html